# Two-Phase commit in EJB

Tags: ejb, jms, weblogic, jta

I getting Two-Phase commit Exption in my application for one of the datasource. Point is application only does ready only data option using Oracle Toplink. Here is what happling in Application

1. Request come to webservice
2. Webservice calls  to JMS Queue. Application need response from queue so used queue with Read Respose
3. In Message Bean( Lets call this ProcessBean), several successful hit goes to Oracle DB  using Oracle Toplink, [b]no exception is trown[/b].
4. After DB data read pointer goes to call to Blaze rule RMI API provided by Blaze.  we get successful result.
5. Queue Calles Response Queue and Response Message is send back.
6. Now exception comes  and Pointer again come to ProcessingBean
7. In webservice never get response back.

P.S. If you desible Global transation in Weblogic connection Pool then everything works fine.  Or If I checked enable Two-Phase commit then also everything is working fine.

Comment: Guyes Looking for solution of this problem please help

Comment: found the solution... added usertraction for my JMS class and everything is working fine now.